# `CI` return wrong value

Tags: codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I have no idea why my `CI` return wrong value from `phpMyAdmin`
Model :

```
    <?php

class Post extends CI_Model
{
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

}
function getallpost()
{
    return $this->db->get('post');


}

}
?>
```

And

Controller :

```
    <?php 

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Postc extends CI_Controller {
    function index()
    {
    $this->load->model('post');
    $posts=$this->post->getallpost();
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($posts);

    }
}
?>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXZ6T.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is not giving you any error, it is doing exactly what you are asking it to do. Perhaps you need to be specific about the information you want to get. You see in your model

```
function getallpost()
{
 return $this->db->get('post');
}
```

The above function will return you an object. If you want to get an array you need to write

```
return $this->db->get('post')->result_array();
```

And make sure you have some data in your post table to print For learning more about query database you should read Codeigniter's [Query Builder Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)

Comment: up you go :). Also read https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html for standard practices to create views

Answer (score 1):

> Change your Model Code

```
<?php
    class Post extends CI_Model
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }
        function getallpost()
        {
            $query = $this->db->get('post');
            if($query->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                return $query->result();
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No need for ?> on models close or controller close https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#php-closing-tag

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get return your result as as array then use

```
return $this->db->get('post')->result_array();
```

And if you want to get return your result as object then use

```
return $this->db->get('post')->result();
```